# Unserialize() is Not Working, Uncaught Error: Call to a member function on boolean

Tags: php, oop, serialization

I have 3 classes, which i serialize and save to the database. 2 of them ork just fine, i am able to retrieve the object and unserialize them without a problem. The class in question has 9 properties. I pass on an array to the class, while saving:

```
  $customer= new Customer($customerValues);
  $serializedCustomer = serialize($customer);
  $auftrag = new Auftrag($auftragValues);
  $serializedAuftrag = serialize($auftrag);
```

the Customer object looks like:

```
O:5:"Customer"?:{s:9:"*anrede";s:4:"Herr";s:7:"*name";s:11:"ABC";s:8:"*firma";s:11:"test";s:10:"*strasse";s:16:"teststr. 33";s:6:"*plz";s:5:"1234";s:8:"*stadt";s:12:"testcity";s:8:"*mobil";s:12:"0123456789";s:10:"*telefon";s:12:"0123456789";s:8:"*email";s:18:"test@mail.com";}
```

and the Auftrag object:

```
O:7:"Auftrag":37:{s:14:"*auftrag_typ";s:7:"Angebot";s:9:"*breite";s:3:"2.5";s:8:"*tiefe";s:3:"4.5";s:8:"*hoehe";s:4:"1.00".....
```

I have the following function in both classes:

```
public function getProperties() {
      $properties = get_object_vars($this);
      return $properties;
    }
```

and i fetch the data from the database and unserialize them:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/Customer.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/Auftrag.php');

$res = $dbc->fetchAllResults(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$custArr = unserialize($res[0]['customer']);
$auftragArr = unserialize($res[0]['auftrag']);
$customer= $custArr->getProperties();
$auftrag = $auftragArr->getProperties();
```

When i print: `print("<pre>".print_r($customer,true)."</pre>");`
i get an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProperties() on boolean in`, but it works completely fine (i get an Array), when i print: `print("<pre>".$auftrag,true)."</pre>");`
When i use: `print("<pre>".$res[0]['customer'],true)."</pre>");` i get the object, like above.

These two objects are near to identical, except for the properties. I noticed, there is a "?" in Customer `"Customer"?:`. Could that be an issue? Or what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by doing the following:

```
$toDatabse = base64_encode(serialize($data));  // Save to database
$fromDatabase = unserialize(base64_decode($data)); //Getting Save Format
```

while the solution from @astax was also correct at pointing out the problem. But by using base64_encode, it ensured to safely serialize the object. This prevents the data from getting corrupted since base64 converts the data to ASCII which any collation can take.

Answer (score -1):

According to [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), `unserialize` returns `false` if the string is invalid. This is what happens in your case - `$custArr` is not an instance of the `Customer` class, hence the error.

If you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` just before unserialize, you'll see the error message, since unserialize throws a notice in case of error. There is indeed something wrong with the serialized string.

My guess is that there are some non-ASCII symbols in the values of the object and you lose them after saving and reading from the database due to mismatching character set. If you use MySQL, this page may help - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html

Comment: i get ```Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 14 of 328 bytes in``` when i use error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I dropped the table and created it again with charset utf-8 and created a new class, but the error persists. I really don't know what could be the cause

Comment: @tmzafar, PHP serialized data is NOT a string-safe value for some databases as it contains zero-bytes (\0). The database may not like them (BTW, you didn't say what DB you're using). Also re-creating the table with UTF-8 encoding is likely not enough for two reasons: 1) apart from DB encoding, there is client encoding (your db connection string); 2) the text may contain emoji, which require 4-byte encoding (utf8mb4 in MySQL). Simply speaking, your best bet is to convert serialized string to ASCII-safe using `base64_encode()` before storing to the db. And `base64_decode()` before unserializing

Comment: Even better - do not store serialized objects in DB, but store them in a relational DB style - not a Customer object, but customer_id, which is a reference to another table.